# Issue with Silverlight interop with JBoss WebService

Tags: java, silverlight, interop, jboss, jax-ws

I have a simple JAXWS webservice deployed in JBoss. It runs fine with a java client but I'm trying to connect using a Silverlight 3.0 application. I've changed the webservice to use Soap 1.1:

```
@BindingType(value = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/http")
public class UserSessionBean implements UserSessionRemote {
...
}
```

I'm using BasicHttpBinding on the Silverlight client.

There are two issues:

1- When I connect from VisualStudio (2008 and 2010) to create the webservice proxies, the following exception is thrown, but the proxy is generated successfully. This also happens when I try to update the existing web service reference (but it also updates fine).

```
com.sun.xml.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:291)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:287)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.decodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:276)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$500(HttpAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:432)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.metro.RequestHandlerImpl.doPost(RequestHandlerImpl.java:225)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.metro.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:82)
    at org.jboss.wsf.common.servlet.AbstractEndpointServlet.service(AbstractEndpointServlet.java:85)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

2- When I use the proxy to fetch some data from the webservice (even methods with primitive types), I get the following error on Silverlight client:

"An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'http://localhost:9090/admintool/UserSessionEJB'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception for more details."

Setting a breakpoint on my java code, I can see that it is not hit when I run the silverlight client, so it is probably a cross domain issue, but I'm not sure how to handle it (I've already created a crossdomain.xml file and put it beside my HTML page hosting the silverlight client).

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Your crossdomain.xml file has to be host at the root of the "website" hosting the webservice. For instance if your endpoint address is http://www.mywebsite:8080/webservice/myendpoint, your crossdomain.xml file must be available at the adresse  http://www.mywebsite:8080/crossdomain.xml
Same host, same port at the root directory.
You have to refer to the JBoss documentation to see how to put a file at the root of the server.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Crossdomain.xml, the fact is the file is in place (as mentioned above), but the error displayed here is not at runtime, it is at code-generation time when you create proxy objects in visual studio.